# Adding slides to previous section - Beamer

Tags: beamer

My presentation is consisted of 4 consecutive slides. I want to divide them in 2 sections. My code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
            \mode<presentation>
                    {\usetheme{Frankfurt}
                     \usecolortheme{lily}
                     \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
    \setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

    \begin{document}

    \section{Numerical examples}
    \begin{frame}
    Example 1
    \end{frame}

    \section{Results}
    \begin{frame}
    Results 1
    \end{frame}

    \section{Numerical examples}
    \begin{frame}
    Example 2
    \end{frame}

    \section{Results}
    \begin{frame}
    Results 2
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

I have something like this:

[image]

Because they have the same names, I would like to achieve the following results:

[image]

How can I add slide to the previous section?

Comment: I am confused. You have four `\section` commands and yet you say you only want two sections? I don't understand what you are trying to do; if you just want two sections, use only two `\section` commands.

Answer (score 1):

USe only two `\section` command and also the possibility of a title for the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{lily}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

    \section{Numerical examples}
    \begin{frame}
    Example 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Results}
    Results 1
    \end{frame}

    \section{Numerical examples}
    \begin{frame}
    Example 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Results}
    Results 2
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You example does not run, it's missing a backslash

Comment: Also, it doesn't answer the question